# Spyder command line

Tags: python, command-line, spyder

I'm using spyder for python programing.
I've a file.py and I want to run code like:

```
--model=RNN --optimizer=SGD
```

but when I run it in the spyder console it gives this error:
`SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`

So how can I run this?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please take a look at the question I referenced above. It explains graphically how to pass command line args to your Python file when executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spyder, if you go into the **Run** menu, you'll find an option named **Configuration per file**. On my system, you can get directly to that entry with CTRL+F6 (the shortcut key may be different on other OSs).

Once you select the menu item, you'll get a dialog window with several options. The one you want is about halfway down, named **Command line options**. You will want to check the box, and put the arguments you showed above into the adjacent text field. Now when you run the file, the code will behave as if those options were passed to it on the command line (it will see them in `sys.argv`).

Comment: Thank you it works